# Reverse accessor clash

Tags: django

I'm trying to be able to assign multiple jobs to an invoice/purchase, however I'm running into an issue. Am I missing something? Does this need to be a many-to-many or something?

I'm getting the following error:

```
invoices.Job.job: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Job.job' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Job.job'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Job.job' or 'Job.job'.
purchases.Job.job: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Job.job' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Job.job'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Job.job' or 'Job.job'.
```

purchases/models.py

```
class Purchase(models.Model):
...

class Job(models.Model):
    purchase = models.ForeignKey(Purchase)
    job = models.ForeignKey('jobs.Job')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.job
```

invoices/models.py

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
...

class Job(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice)
    job = models.ForeignKey('jobs.Job')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.job
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to change the related names in foreign key and possibly rename the models for clarity.

```
# i dont recommended ever naming 2 models the exact same way either

class PurchaseJob(models.Model):
    purchase = models.ForeignKey(Purchase, related_name='purchase_job')

class InvoiceJob(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, related_name='invoice_job')
```

Adding related names keeps naming conventions clean and neat, also you avoid alot of Django errors by doing so.