# Reverse accessor for X clashes with reverse accessor for Y

Tags: python, django

Following are two fields in a class of `models.py`. These are two keys refereed as foreign key from same key of another table.

```
permenantpincode = models.ForeignKey(Pincodemap, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='PermenantPincode')
localpincode = models.ForeignKey(Pincodemap, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='LocalPincode')  # Field name made lowercase.
```

This is showing following error while migration.

ERRORS:

> Volunteer.localpincode: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for
>   'Volunteer.localpincode' clashes with reverse accessor for
>   'Volunteer.permenantpincode'.

How could I fix this ?

Comment: You may also take a look at: [Django: reverse accessors for foreign keys clashing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22538563/django-reverse-accessors-for-foreign-keys-clashing)

Comment: [Reverse accessors for foreign keys clashing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22538563/608639), [Django Reverse Accessor Clashes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26955319/608639), [Reverse accessor clash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29526302/608639), [Django: reverse accessors for foreign keys clashing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22538563/608639), etc.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it using  above references.